# Rounded corners in outlook without images

Tags: html, css, email

I can create rounded corners in many clients with

```
style="-moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;"
```

However this CSS does not create rounded corners in Outlook. Is there any easy way to create rounded corners without images in Outlook?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: Follow up question: Would it be a bad idea to simply turn the button into an image? Normally this is a bad practice but I wonder if this is an exception?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ displays all css supported in major email clients. Rounded borders didn't even make it to the list. On the page there is a link to a full PDF, which notes that border radius is **ONLY** supported in Thunderbird 2

please note that you have to embed the styles in the html elements to support a broad range of email clients

You can find the full list of supported HTML elements and CSS styles in the following series of articles:

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: If you use the [complete guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/downloads/documents-tools/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-sept-2011.pdf) border radius is listed. The guide seems wrong, I know for a fact that it is supported in Gmail, as it is working right now for me. However I feel web email clients are very browser dependent.

Comment: ow you mean its working with gmail wich is rendered by your browser?

Comment: Ya, it works in gmail which is rendered by my browser, but not in Outlook Web Access which is rendered by my browser too. So the guide still seems wrong to me by saying that it isn't supported in gmail.

Comment: why are you looking at gmail anyway? isnt the question about outlook?

Comment: Yes, the question was about Outlook. I was looking at gmail because when I saw that it wasn't supported on the guide when I knew it partially is (depending on your browser) makes me question whether the guide is a good reference or not.

Comment: Are you using Outlook Web Access in the same browser you're using gmail in? OWA seems to want IE pretty bad, and IE is notorious for not supporting... anything.

Comment: The border radius also works fine in OSX Mail and the email on all iPhones/iPads and I think Androids too. I recon the Microsoft Outlook team should just steel the rendering code from the IE9 engine which works pretty good.

Comment: Just found an article on active campaign about newest Outlook 2013, http://litmus.com/blog/outlook-2013-still-powered-by-word-now-available-for-email-testing
I don't think Outlook will be supporting radius borders anytime soon.

Comment: the funny thing is: 7 years after this post, border-radius and a lot of other basic css still is not supported by outlook. :D plus, we still are happy to use `table` instead of `div`

Answer (score 81):

This code produces buttons with rounded corners in Outlook 2010 using the Outlook conditional comments () and VML:

```
    <div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
            Button Text Here!
        </center>
    </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]> <!-->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>
        <td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#d62828" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
            <a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                Button Text Here!
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr> </table>
    <!-- <![endif]-->
</div>
```

Tested in Outlook 2010 and major browsers only, not OWA, Outlook.com or any mobile browsers. It's worth a closer look. Credit where due -- http://www.industrydive.com/blog/how-to-make-html-email-buttons-that-rock/

Comment: This is a good solution. You need to get creative to not duplicate your content, but it works!

Comment: It's a little dirty woraround, but (as I understand) - Microsoft products - are totally workarounds. 

Thank you.

Comment: @yAnTar: It is funny. Microsoft declare VML as deprecated as IE9, but the new Outlook2017 still use VML to draw rectangles, not SVG as it should be since 2011: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this answer it lead me to my solution to the same problem. I posted another answer to this question which shows my end solution.

Comment: Can someone confirm it performs in Outlook 2007, 13, and 16 as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work on version 1908 of Outlook, the text is clipped vertically and can't be read.

Comment: I am also facing same problem.  roundrect is not working. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Text clips are possibly due to there not being enough height on the Outlook code. Increase the height, and/or decrease the line-height (make it the same as the font-size). Then you can see the text.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using https://buttons.cm/ which will generate something like this:

```
<div>
  <!--[if mso]>
    <v:roundrect 
      xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
      href="http://TEST.com" 
      style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" 
      arcsize="10%" 
      stroke="f" 
      fillcolor="#B7D636">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://TEST.com"
         style="background-color:#B7D636;
                border-radius:4px;
                color:#ffffff;
                display:inline-block;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:13px;
                font-weight:bold;
                line-height:40px;
                text-align:center;
                text-decoration:none;
                width:200px;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
              TEXT
            </a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
</div>
```

Note that the most bulletproof kind of button is a button that is an image. That way the whole element will be clickable, it will survive email forwarding, and all email clients will support it without bugs.

Comment: The least bulletproof button is an image. - Many email clients load the email without images and give the option to download the images. - The alt text of a link is not nearly as obvious of a call-to-action as an actual button. - Using images opens you up to the risk of broken image links, whereas a coded button will always render, even if not always in the exact style one might prefer. - Images increase your email size. On a corporate level, this could slow down send rates of mass distributions. - Images for buttons is generally not considered an ideal practice.

Comment: what if I want rounded corners on a table background? Simple colour?

Answer (score 7):

Further to @VanAlberts answer which shows Eli Dickinson's great work. Here is a link to Eli's git repo https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/9424116

I thought I would share my improvement to Eli's code which allows for dynamic width button based on the text inside.

I found this https://litmus.com/community/discussions/538-vml-outlook-07-10-13-unwanted-20px-padding-at-the-bottom which shows how to use `mso-fit-shape-to-text:true`

And this https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1269-flexible-multi-line-bulletproof-buttons which shows how to avoid some unwanted padding.

This is my end result

```
<div>
<!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="mso-wrap-style:none; mso-position-horizontal: center" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#0368d4" strokeweight="1px" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true">
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">Button Text Here!</center>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:roundrect>
  <![endif]-->
  <![if !mso]>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr> 
  <td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#d62828" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
    <a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">
      Button Text Here!
    </span>
    </a>
  </td> 
  </tr> </table> 
  <![endif]>
</div>
```

Seems to work great in outlook 2016 which uses word to render HTML

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to just not use rounded corners.. after long times of testing, both with Litmus, on multiple clients - rounded corners using the ways suggested such as:

```
<div>
<!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="mso-wrap-style:none; mso-position-horizontal: center" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#0368d4" strokeweight="1px" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true">
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">Button Text Here!</center>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:roundrect>
  <![endif]-->
  <![if !mso]>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr> 
  <td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#d62828" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
    <a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">
      Button Text Here!
    </span>
    </a>
  </td> 
  </tr> </table> 
  <![endif]>
</div>
```

Will break on GMAIL when forwarding, when forwarding this type of code to GMAIL - it will try to re-create it because it won't contain the condition any longer and will generate the following code as example:

```
<div style="margin-top:36.0pt">
   <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" dir="RTL" style="text-align:center;direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:embed">
      <span dir="LTR" style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2d3b4a">
         <u></u>
         <span>
            <map name="m_3406853463519709989_MicrosoftOfficeMap0">
               <area shape="Polygon" coords="38, 2, 13, 12, 3, 37, 13, 62, 38, 72, 228, 72, 253, 62, 263, 37, 253, 12, 228, 2, 38, 2" href="https://local.greeninvoice.co.il/app/account/verify?key=001dEbYWSscdPxI8xt6BcS%2B%2BrA%3D%3D" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://local.greeninvoice.co.il/app/account/verify?key%3D001dEbYWSscdPxI8xt6BcS%252B%252BrA%253D%253D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1520336994067000&amp;usg=AFQjCNE1iYP97qNrlsCccYFgDyRW3iVPRw">
            </map>
            <img border="0" width="264" height="74" src="?ui=2&amp;ik=4e1d22bf20&amp;view=fimg&amp;th=161f5fb79e36447b&amp;attid=0.1&amp;disp=emb&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_3ejUStIrGp0uslTPSXPSph1LGDDnyTH2gHxWhcMpCHN_CjO4ZYsqbvqZJ9gXCxQ7e3KHV2CAn0f-FWPYH7w7lTM9ym54909Upm-h_G9W--o_I431bc9U3icg&amp;sz=w528-h148&amp;ats=1520250594056&amp;rm=161f5fb79e36447b&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" usemap="#m_3406853463519709989_MicrosoftOfficeMap0" alt="Rounded Rectangle: הפעלת החשבון " class="CToWUd">
         </span>
         <u></u>
      </span>
      <span lang="HE" style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#2d3b4a"><u></u><u></u></span>
   </p>
</div>
```

This as you can see will break the width, height, text, center of stuff and happens because VML is a proprietary Microsoft language and Outlook converts it to a map when forwarding

[image]