# CSS Styling won't work in outlook?

Tags: css, outlook

I use styling in my outlook.
But some style does not work.

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: email client ? use a image

Comment: which browser u r using???

Comment: you can get help from [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images

please check if it helps

Comment: `border-radius` is not supported. Take a look at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I have used for the logo image. But I need to use the style for the button

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
       <style type="text/css">
        padding: 5px 10px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius: 8px;
       border-radius: 8px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
       -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
       box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
       text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
       color: white;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-family: Georgia, serif;
       text-decoration: none;
       vertical-align: middle;
       mso-line-height-rule: exactly;

</style>
```