# Using CSS circles in Email

Tags: html, css, email, mailchimp, inline-code

I'm trying to create a nice round circle with a number in the middle, I have it working fine in my browser, but when I go to send in MailChimp the circles become huge squares.

This is my CSS

```
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ff8080

    }
```

Then I am using -

`<div class="circle">1</div>`

This is in my browser - [Circle in Browser](http://oi59.tinypic.com/dnn2x3.jpg)
This is in Outlook - [Cirlces in Outlook](http://oi60.tinypic.com/vgonjc.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded corners in outlook without images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Comment: A lot of email clients don't support css3, if you want circles in the email, you would have to use images.

Comment: I think it's because with Outlook, you have to use Table and not Div. I don't know why, but I have a lot of problems with div on Outlook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a fix that works perfectly -

```
<div align="center"><!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:100px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="600%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ff8080">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center>
<![endif]-->
  <a href="http://"
  style="background-color:#ff8080;border-radius:600px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:100px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">1</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A lot of email clients don't support CSS3, as a result you won't be able to use border-radius.

If you wish to have circles in your emails, you would have to use images.