# Rounded Corners for containers displaying in Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email, rounded-corners, vml

I'm trying to wrap content to display in an HTML email in a container that will display with rounded corners.

I wanted to even show the rounded corners when the recipient views it from Outlook so I was hoping to use VML's "roundrect" as described in:
https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/9424116#file-html_email_buttons_1-html

It looks like this only works for fixed sized content though.  My container would need to grow to fit the size of the content.  Is there anyway to make roundrect do that?

Is there any better option for displaying rounded corners in Outlook? I'd like to stay away from using images for the rounded corners.

Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question which may be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images/48178955#48178955

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can recall if you are creating a button using VML then it needs to have a fixed width and height.

If you are creating a background image then dont need the width and height. [Background.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) is a really good resource for you to create VML based buttons or backgrounds. Hope that helps.

Cheers