# HTML table content alignment

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:40px;line-height:2px;color:red;">◖</td> 
    <td style="width:80px;height:30px;background-color:red;"></td> 
    <td style="font-size:40px;line-height:2px;color:red;">◗</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hvx8ek92/12/)

What I want to do is to appear my table content as the `div` below ( with border radius )

```
<div style="width:120px;height:30px;background-color:red;border-radius:50px;"></div>
```

I have to do it with table like this because this code will use in html email for Outlook Desktop client which doesn't support `border-radius` .

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: sorry , wrong fiddle , I've updated my question .
The problem is , there is a space between half-circles and rectangle between them .

Comment: yes, I know the half-circle itself has space , but is there any way ?
Like using padding with minus values ? I've tried this , but doesn't work .

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <div style="padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
         font-size: 40px;
         line-height: 2px;
         color: red;
         background-image: url(http://freshcodelabel.com/images/red-half-circle.png);
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         transform: rotate(180deg);
         height: 186px;
         width:90px;
         display:inline-block;
         ">
      </div>
      <div style="width: 212px;height: 179px;background-color:#c60000;display:inline-block;"></div>
      <div style="
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
         font-size: 40px;
         line-height: 2px;
         color: red;
         background-image: url(http://freshcodelabel.com/images/red-half-circle.png);
         height: 186px;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         width:90px;
         display:inline-block;
         background-position: 0px 7px;
         "></div>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htx1mfg0)

Use images instead of characters.

Comment: nice trick , but I should avoid using image url because outlook (desktop) block image url sometime . so it's alittle buggy .

Comment: [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images) check these answers maybe these would work out for you

Answer (score 0):

Completely based on div.

```css
div.my-button{
  padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #e9703e;
  background-color: #EB7035;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 119px;
}
div.my-button a{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-button">
 <a href="http://litmus.com" target="_blank">I am a button &rarr;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: They cannot use `border-radius` as it is not supported on Outlook Desktop Client