# Border radius not working in email templates on Windows Outlook

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, border

I am facing a `border-radius` issue in an email template on the Outlook app. I have tried with `-WebKit-border-radius` and `-ms-border-radius` as well, but it's still not working in Outlook app.

```css
table {
  width: 32px !important;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -ms-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" height="32" width="32" bgcolor="#293248" cellspacing="0 " cellpadding="0 "></table>
```

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Here is my code
<table align="center" height="32" width="32" style="width: 32px !important; border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;" bgcolor="#293248" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

Comment: @ChandanRathore You can edit your question, and put the code inside.

Comment: Can you post the code so we can understand clearly to solve your problem?

Comment: @ArshiyaKhanam I have just edited my comment, So now you can see my code.

Comment: Use this -moz-border-radius: 50px;

Comment: @ArshiyaKhanam I have already used this but it's not working :)

Comment: Here's the list for [border-radius](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border-radius/) support in email clients. There is nothing you can do, as `background-image` doesn't work as well. The whole point in disabling some CSS properties is to take a way any means by which developers can alter email HTML contents, so that users can't be deceived. Emails are not web pages they should be largely viewed as pimped text messages (think sms). If you want to present web content to your user, present them a link to the page. By the way, Outlook creates this link (and the page) automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Answer (score 10):

CSS3 is not supported by Outlook, as border radius is CSS3 property and it won't work in Outlook. But their are alternative solutions to your problem. Use below Code it will work in Outlook as it is tested in Outlook 2010,2013,2016,2019

```
    <div>
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:300px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d62828">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
        Button Text Here!
    </center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]> <!-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>
    <td align="center" width="300" height="40" bgcolor="#d62828" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
        <a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
            Button Text Here!
        </a>
    </td>
</tr> </table>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```