# HTML Email - putting "badge" formatting around text

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I'm sending HTML emails and want to style some text with "badges" around it. The code below works on Outlook Web and Thunderbird but not on Outlook native Windows 10.

While it looks like this in the success cases:

[image]

The text looks like this on Outlook for Windows 10:

[image]

I do not require that they look identical, I just want it to not look bad. So if somebody has a completely different styling idea, I'm open to it.

---

Other technical information

- The only email clients I care about are Outlook (Windows 10 native, Office 365, currently 1902), Outlook Web for Office 365 and Thunderbird (recent versions).
- I have verified that the systems used to send emails do not strip parts of the html/css off.
- Here is a minimal reproducible test-case

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffc107;
}
```

```html
Badges with embedded sytesheet <span class="badge ">v1.1.1</span>&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-pill badge-branch">v1.1.2</span>

<br>
Badges with inline style
<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 0.25em 0.4em; font-size: 75%; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; top: -1px; padding-right: 0.6em; padding-left: 0.6em; border-radius: 10rem; color: #212529; background-color: #ffc107;">v2.0.0</span>&nbsp;
<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 0.25em 0.4em; font-size: 75%; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; top: -1px; padding-right: 0.6em; padding-left: 0.6em; border-radius: 10rem; color: #212529; background-color: #ffc107;">v2.0.1</span>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe rounded borders are not supported in the outlook, and if you're not using webpack or other stuff like that, I think you have to add these two `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` to your code also, to add extra supporting for `border-radius`. Also, there is a similar question in the community that could help you with your issue, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7405493/11908502) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the referenced StackOverfloverflow answer and to be honest, I really don't want to start adding lots of proprietary VML to my email, for me that would be unmaintainable. I suspect I'd just be looking for some alternate "different but also attractive" solution for outlook.

Comment: @Mort if you will be targeting Outlook specifically you will need conditional statements as well.

Comment: Yes, for sure. I'm resigned to a little conditional css, but I just want it to be sensible, not crazy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with loading images from an external server, try using [shields.io](https://shields.io).
try adding `<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/-Your Text Here-yellow">` instead of the badge css.
If that doesn’t show, add .png to the end.

It will look like [image]

Comment: Did it work in Outlook without the .png at the end?