# How to display Border Radius on Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an Email Template which is working fine for all Gmail, Yahoo etc. But in Outlook it is not working. Can anyone please help me how to make it visible on Outlook.

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px;">
<p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Hello</span></span></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;${mail_script:notification_logo}</p>
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 40px;" colspan="5">
<p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">You Project(${URI_REF}) has been submitted and is being reviewed by&nbsp;<strong>${u_project_manager}</strong>.</span></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Title</strong></span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${short_description}</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Submitted by</strong></span></span></td>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Approver</strong></span></span></td>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Department</strong></span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${submitter}</span></span></td>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${u_project_manager}</span></span></td>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">${department}</span></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;">Thank you,<br /></span><span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">IT Service Desk</span></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Outlook does not support CSS3 styles. Border radius is CSS3 hence it is not visible in Outlook but in Gmail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Comment: @Abdul Azeez Please put my code, it will work in your outlook as well.

Answer (score 3):

Only Outlook on IOS devices supports border-radius.
The Windows version out Outlook does not support border-radius since it uses Microsoft Word as its processor.

see camapaign monitor:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border-bottom/

Answer (score 0):

Although you can try the below code, if it helps solving your problem.

```html
<body>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="300" height="40" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;background-color:#000;text-align:center;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
               Test
            </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div style="border: 2px solid grey;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px;">
    <p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Hello</span></span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="height: 40px;" colspan="5">
            <p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">You Project( Lorem ipsum  ) has been submitted and is being reviewed by&nbsp;<strong>Lorem ipsum </strong>.</span></span>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Title</strong></span></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: black;" colspan="5"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Lorem ipsum </span></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Submitted by</strong></span></span>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Approver</strong></span></span>
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;"><strong>Department</strong></span></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: black;" colspan="3"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Lorem ipsum </span></span>
          </td>
          <td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Lorem ipsum </span></span>
          </td>
          <td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 300;">Lorem ipsum </span></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span style="font-family: 'museo-sans', sans-serif;"><span style="font-weigth: 500;">Thank you,<br /></span><span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">IT Service Desk</span></span>
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sir,
Can you please help me in adding the above code to my code ?
I am very poor in Front end, if possible please help me in adding the above code to your code ? so i can test ?

Comment: Some of the attribute in your example are obsolete. `align` and `bgcolor`. The vendor prefixes are not needed anymore either. Do not use this example.

Comment: @AbdulAzeez Kindly provide a valid HTML markup, where you are facing the issue. Above Code of yours seems to be some template, kindly paste only HTML

Comment: @Rob agree with you.incorporated the suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Sir, As said it is not my written i am working on it which was designed by someone else in the past. I am actually not a matured Front End Developer i am a pure ServiceNow Developer works on JavaScript. Since it is assigned to me i am working on it. I am sorry

Comment: @AbdulAzeez tried editing your code kindly change to your way. Relevant code is in the first line of "div"

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Where did you change the code ? did you upload the snippet ? i dont see any changes

Comment: @AbdulAzeez Please refer above attached screenshot

Comment: Thank You. But it is not displaying in Outlook :(

Comment: Either of the styles mentioned (`-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;`) will not work in Outlook. Look at @awis's comment where he points you to a way to make rounded edges in Outlook

Comment: @Rob is wrong. This is email development, not front-end development. `align` and `bgcolor` are not out of date because various versions of Outlook, older versions of Android no matter how out-of-date they may be, have a huge installed base and developers need to use the best attributes that work, even if they are obsolete in front-end development.