# Border-radius not working in outlook client

Tags: html, css, outlook

```html
   "<tr> <td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #6f6f6f; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; padding: 20px;' align='left'>";
                             "<!--[if mso]><v:roundrect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' herf='http://www.EXAMPLE.com/' style='v-text-anchor:middle;width:600px;' arcsize='30%' stroke='f' fillcolor='#eeebeb'><w:anchorlock/>";
                             "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style=border-collapse: collapse;'><tbody><tr cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style=' border-collapse: collapse;'>"
                             "<td id='updatebox-rcorners2' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style='padding: 10px; max-width: 100%; font-size: 14px;text-align: justify; background-color: #eeebeb;'>";
                             "<p><strong>" + solution + ":</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " + uptab[i] + "</p><b>" + strupdate + ":</b>" + updecDt[i] + "<div style='align:right;'> <div> &nbsp;" + Estdate + "</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>";
                          "</v:roundrect><![endif]-->";
                           "<!--[if !mso]><!--><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center' width='300' height='40' bgcolor='#d62828' style='-webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; color #ffffff; display:block;'><a  href='http://www.EXAMPLE.com/' style='color:#ffffff; display:inline-block'>";
                            "<div id='updatebox-rcorners2' style='border-radius: 25px;solid #000000; padding: 10px; max-width: 100%; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: #eeebeb;'>";
                          "<p><strong>" + solution + ":</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " + uptab[i] + "</p><b>" + strupdate + ":</b>" + updecDt[i] + "<div style='float:right;'> <div>" + Estdate + "<div></div></div></div></div></div> <br></div></td></tr></a></td></tr></table><!-- <![endif]-->";
```

I want round corners for my email which I am sending trough smtp. it is working for gmail as well as in outlook web but not working in outlook client 2016.

I want this following code to work on outlook 2016. can you help how i can achive it.

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'><tbody><tr><td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #6f6f6f; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; padding: 20px;' align='left'>                        
<div style='border-radius: 25px; border: 0px solid #000000; padding: 10px; max-width: 100%; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: #eeebeb;'>
<p><strong> Solution : </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {4}</p><b>Updated Date:</b>{5}</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I have used this it works but for one tag only. but i want output as this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg5MX.png)

but i am getting this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF7Sz.png)

here is my code.

" ";
"";
""
"";
"

**" + solution + ":**      " + uptab[i] + "

**" + strupdate + ":**" + updecDt[i] + "   " + Estdate + "";
"";
"";
"";
"

**" + solution + ":**      " + uptab[i] + "

**" + strupdate + ":**" + updecDt[i] + " " + Estdate + " 
";

ignore ("") this.

Comment: <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'><tbody><tr><td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #6f6f6f; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; padding: 20px;' align='left'>                        

<div style='border-radius: 25px; border: 0px solid #000000; padding: 10px; max-width: 100%; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify; background-color: #eeebeb;'>
<p><strong> Solution : </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {4}</p><b>Updated Date:</b>{5}</div></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images). The answers are ancient but the linked website still works, and shows that outlook 2016 doesn't support `border-radius`

Comment: Border-radius is not supported in Outlook, need to use images or accept corners

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Comment: hi all thank u for ur help Rounded corners in outlook without images. but doesn't helped me