# Rounded corners for table heading only

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I need to create html template for email with pricing plans. I'm trying to recreate given design from `png` file

Problem: This is easy recreate at browser email services, but in Outlook desktop things just doesn`t work.

How can i reach results like on image?

[image: 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Comment: You can use VML (link by Nathan) or you can use images for rounded corners only and the rest being HTML. Only drawback is if images are not loaded, your table edges might look a little ... odd.