# How to create curved shape for email template

Tags: html, css, email, css-transitions, html-email

I'm trying to create an email template, but in email (Outlook/Gmail), borderRadius isn't supported. Is there any way to create it using Canvas or any other CSS method? I can't directly use an image because it contains clickable links.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners in outlook without images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405493/rounded-corners-in-outlook-without-images)

Comment: Noting Gmail does in fact support border-radius https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-border-radius/

Answer (score 1):

I’m not an expert in HTML email but I know that tables are still used heavily, so perhaps you could build this as a table, using background images in the corner cells.

[image]

Comment: That would work. You can also just do this for Outlook desktop using conditional comments, and leave border-radius for everything else.